# Split audio with AudioIntervals

Tags: sound

How do I split an Audio object into multiple ones, where the *i*th object represents the *i*th interval satisfying a certain criterion?
A quick and dirty solution I just thought of is this:

```
a = Import["test.wav"]
int = AudioIntervals[a, #RMSAmplitude < .01 &]
a_split = AudioSplit[a, Flatten[int]]
a_split_rms = a_split[[Range[2, Length[a_split], 2]]]
```

But there are obviously lots of edge cases it doesn't catch.

Comment: Have you seen `AudioTrim[]`?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @J.M. For some reason, "AudioTrim Mathematica" doesn't show up on Google results. Anyway, that looks like the solution for what I want.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`AudioTrim[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AudioTrim.html).

```
a = Import["test.wav"]
asplit = AudioTrim[a, AudioIntervals[a, #RMSAmplitude < 0.1 &]]
```

`asplit` will now contain the segmented Audio objects.

Comment: BTW: the underscore is a special character in *Mathematica*, and not to be used in variable names.

Comment: @J.M. Okay, thanks!